# Logstash replacing @timestamp

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash to keep track of my logs.
I use file as input and elasticsearch as output.
my config file looks like this:

```
    input{
  file{
    path => "C:\products.logs"
    format => "json"
  }
}
filter{
}
output{
  elasticsearch{
    host => localhost
  }
}
```

the file is filled with lines of logs and each log looks something like this:

```
    {"ID":65464,"Name":"Tracker_56213453.xml","sender_sent_time":"10/04/2014 14:14:40","insertion_time":"10/04/2014 14:14:40","Is_Valid":true}
```

as you can see, there is more then 1 value which holds time format.
when I tried to add this date filter:

```
    filter{
      date{
        match=>["insertion_time","dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
      }
    }
```

but it didn't work.
what am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Your dates aren't dd/MM/YYYY for one....

Answer (score 0):

The default [target](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#target) for date is `@timestamp`.  If you want to convert in place, you'll want to add a `target => insertion_time`

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should look like the following:

```
 filter{
  date{
    match=>["insertion_time","dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => ["insertion_time"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
filter {
    # match date and time
    date {
        "match"  => ["insertion_time", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
        "target" => "insertion_time"
    }
}
```